# Perlin Noise for game terrain; math error (unexpected breaks in terrain (3D grid))

Tags: c++, 3d-meshes, debugging, perlin-noise

So, I'm learning how to generate terrain using Perlin Noise, and I came across this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753055/perlin-noise-generation-for-terrain/4753123#4753123

## PerlinNoise.h

```
    #pragma once

class PerlinNoise
{
public:

  // Constructor
    PerlinNoise();
    PerlinNoise(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed);

  // Get Height
    double GetHeight(double x, double y) const;

  // Get
  double Persistence() const { return persistence; }
  double Frequency()   const { return frequency;   }
  double Amplitude()   const { return amplitude;   }
  int    Octaves()     const { return octaves;     }
  int    RandomSeed()  const { return randomseed;  }

  // Set
  void Set(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed);

  void SetPersistence(double _persistence) { persistence = _persistence; }
  void SetFrequency(  double _frequency)   { frequency = _frequency;     }
  void SetAmplitude(  double _amplitude)   { amplitude = _amplitude;     }
  void SetOctaves(    int    _octaves)     { octaves = _octaves;         }
  void SetRandomSeed( int    _randomseed)  { randomseed = _randomseed;   }

private:

    double Total(double i, double j) const;
    double GetValue(double x, double y) const;
    double Interpolate(double x, double y, double a) const;
    double Noise(int x, int y) const;

    double persistence, frequency, amplitude;
    int octaves, randomseed;
};
```

## PerlinNoise.cpp

```
#include "PerlinNoise.h"

PerlinNoise::PerlinNoise()
{
  persistence = 0;
  frequency = 0;
  amplitude  = 0;
  octaves = 0;
  randomseed = 0;
}

PerlinNoise::PerlinNoise(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed)
{
  persistence = _persistence;
  frequency = _frequency;
  amplitude  = _amplitude;
  octaves = _octaves;
  randomseed = 2 + _randomseed * _randomseed;
}

void PerlinNoise::Set(double _persistence, double _frequency, double _amplitude, int _octaves, int _randomseed)
{
  persistence = _persistence;
  frequency = _frequency;
  amplitude  = _amplitude;
  octaves = _octaves;
  randomseed = 2 + _randomseed * _randomseed;
}

double PerlinNoise::GetHeight(double x, double y) const
{
  return amplitude * Total(x, y);
}

double PerlinNoise::Total(double i, double j) const
{
    //properties of one octave (changing each loop)
    double t = 0.0f;
    double _amplitude = 1;
    double freq = frequency;

    for(int k = 0; k < octaves; k++) 
    {
        t += GetValue(j * freq + randomseed, i * freq + randomseed) * _amplitude;
        _amplitude *= persistence;
        freq *= 2;
    }

    return t;
}

double PerlinNoise::GetValue(double x, double y) const
{
    int Xint = (int)x;
    int Yint = (int)y;
    double Xfrac = x - Xint;
    double Yfrac = y - Yint;

  //noise values
  double n01 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint-1);
  double n02 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint-1);
  double n03 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint+1);
  double n04 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint+1);
  double n05 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint);
  double n06 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint);
  double n07 = Noise(Xint, Yint-1);
  double n08 = Noise(Xint, Yint+1);
  double n09 = Noise(Xint, Yint);

  double n12 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint-1);
  double n14 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint+1);
  double n16 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint);

  double n23 = Noise(Xint-1, Yint+2);
  double n24 = Noise(Xint+1, Yint+2);
  double n28 = Noise(Xint, Yint+2);

  double n34 = Noise(Xint+2, Yint+2);

    //find the noise values of the four corners
    double x0y0 = 0.0625*(n01+n02+n03+n04) + 0.125*(n05+n06+n07+n08) + 0.25*(n09);  
    double x1y0 = 0.0625*(n07+n12+n08+n14) + 0.125*(n09+n16+n02+n04) + 0.25*(n06);  
    double x0y1 = 0.0625*(n05+n06+n23+n24) + 0.125*(n03+n04+n09+n28) + 0.25*(n08);  
    double x1y1 = 0.0625*(n09+n16+n28+n34) + 0.125*(n08+n14+n06+n24) + 0.25*(n04);  

    //interpolate between those values according to the x and y fractions
    double v1 = Interpolate(x0y0, x1y0, Xfrac); //interpolate in x direction (y)
    double v2 = Interpolate(x0y1, x1y1, Xfrac); //interpolate in x direction (y+1)
    double fin = Interpolate(v1, v2, Yfrac);  //interpolate in y direction

    return fin;
}

double PerlinNoise::Interpolate(double x, double y, double a) const
{
    double negA = 1.0 - a;
  double negASqr = negA * negA;
    double fac1 = 3.0 * (negASqr) - 2.0 * (negASqr * negA);
  double aSqr = a * a;
    double fac2 = 3.0 * aSqr - 2.0 * (aSqr * a);

    return x * fac1 + y * fac2; //add the weighted factors
}

double PerlinNoise::Noise(int x, int y) const
{
    int n = x + y * 57;
    n = (n << 13) ^ n;
  int t = (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff;
    return 1.0 - double(t) * 0.931322574615478515625e-9;/// 1073741824.0);
}
```

The properties I decided to use were:

- persistence = 1.0
- frequency = 0.1
- amplitude  = 2.0
- octaves = 1.0
- randomseed = 1.0

Once I was able to get it running, I noticed a peculiar bug; plugging in these pairs creates a peculiar break in the terrain:

x  |  z

39  | 39

39  | 40

40  | 39

40  | 40

I then noticed that it appears the terrain creates a border, and generates a new seeded terrain. These new seeds begin at x = +40, and z = +40. Toying around with different seeds, I get the same effect. Sometimes I get multitudes of 7x7 squares that are completely different seeds. I'm not really sure what's happening. At first I thought there was some sort of 3 dimensional tangent going on, but I don't see any trig functions in the code.

This bug appears to occur no matter how I alter the properties.

I realize this is more of a programming question, but i was hoping to find someone more math oriented to see if they could deduce why my terrain (think 3D graph) has breaks in it. It's like they switch to a different method once I plug in more numbers.

Here's an example of my terrain bug. Im using these properties this time:

- persistence = 1.1
- frequency = 0.002
- amplitude  = 10.0
- octaves = 6.0
- randomseed = 1.0

and the break happens at x = 77, z = 77

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25125155/noisebug.png]

Comment: it would have been nicer if you attached some screenshots. even if you don't have enough reputation, you can just upload them and put links in your question.

Comment: added a link at the bottom of the post, as well as some updated info directly above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may lie here:

```
int Xint = (int)x;
int Yint = (int)y;
```

You want the floor value instead, or you will get discontinuities near zero:

```
int Xint = (int)floor(x);
int Yint = (int)floor(y);
```

Comment: Weird... you'd think that the fact it's an interview would automatically floor the value, since it just trims of the decimal, but I guess not. That totally fixed it! Thanks man!

Comment: Int*... dang autocorrect. I would gladly upvote you, but i lack the reputation.

Comment: Conversion to integer gives the integer in the direction of zero. `floor` gives the integer towards negative infinity. `ceil` gives the integer towards positive infinity. Integral conversion is like `floor` for positive numbers and like `ceil` for negative numbers.